# LDAP URI for ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need to create a script that can query users on Active Directory.

Assuming:
All my users are connected to a server called "engineering.software.companyX.com".
All our PC's have domain accounts to the name above.

What LDAP URI do I use?

Comment: By "LDAP name", do you mean the `distinguishedName` of the object?

Comment: when I get a new PC. We join it to the domain. When we get new employees, we add them to active directory. Active Directory knows when the users password will expire, etc. I want to connect to AD but I need to use some LDAP:// format and I don't know what it should be

Comment: Is your AD domain "engineering.software.companyX.com"?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [`dsquery`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952(WS.10).aspx) to query the AD domain.  To get the `distinguishedName` of the computer `myComputer`:

```
dsquery computer -name "myComputer"
  CN=myComputer,CN=Computers,DC=engineering,DC=software,DC=companyX,DC=com
```

You can also query users by their logon name:

```
dsquery user -samid "Administrator"
  "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=engineering,DC=software,DC=companyX,DC=com
```

Edit:

I see from the edits you just want the LDAP connection string/URI.  Try this:

`ldap://DC=engineering,DC=software,DC=companyX,DC=com`